# D3.JS | ReactJS Filter selection 'this' conflict issue

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, filter, attributes, selection

There is a very simple sketch in raw JavaScript

```js
   var actives = { active1: false, active2: true, active3: true, active4: false };

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 512).attr('height', 512);

var rect1 = svg.append("rect").attr("class", "boxElement active1 active2 active3").attr("x", 32).attr("y", 32).attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100).attr("fill", "#888888");

var rect2 = svg.append("rect").attr("class", "boxElement active1 active4").attr("x", 160).attr("y", 32).attr("width", 100).attr("height", 100).attr("fill", "#DDDDDD");

d3.selectAll('.boxElement').filter(function(){ var classes = d3.select(this).attr("class"); console.log(classes); var sum = false; Object.keys(actives).forEach(function(a_){ if(classes.includes(a_)){ console.log("found"); sum += actives[a_]; }}); return sum > 0 ? true : false }).attr("fill", "#00FF00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, console.log(d3.select(this)) return rectangle classes and that's correct. I need to write some function (instead of `d3.select(this).attr("class").includes("whatever")`) inside filter to pick which rects would be cyan based on class variation.

However, I need to do the same thing in ReactJS and it seems that 'this' is reserved and filter console.log(d3.select(this)) return the component itself.

The syntax `.filter(function(item_){ console.log(item_); return true; })` doesn't work as well, it return `undefined` and `console.log(item_.attr("class"))` returns error.

So, how I can access each selection and its attributes one by one at filter method, if `d3.select(this)` doesn't work?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-react-hooks-forked-2lihv?file=/src/index.js Click on blue button.

Comment: Thanks! Is it about the code in `update()`? As soon as I use `.filter(function() { console.log(this);});` instead of `.filter(() => console.log(this));`, the logged value is correct again, otherwise it's undefined.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-react-hooks-forked-2lihv?file=/src/index.js I need to access attr('class'), however filter(() => console.log(this.attr('class'); ) returns error. 'this' is reserved by parent component and I'm looking for solution to access each selection.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an elegant solution, however it works. I am using `.nodes().map(...)`

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as d3 from "d3";

import "./styles.css";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MockupD3 id="d3svg" />
    </div>
  );
}

class MockupD3 extends React.Component {

  constructor(props_) {

    super(props_);
    this.actives = { active1: false, active2: true, active3: true, active4: false };

    this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
  }
  clickMe(){

    let this_ = this;

    d3.selectAll('.box').nodes().map(node_ => {
      
      let sum = 0;
      Object.keys(this_.actives).forEach(key_ =>{

        let classes = node_.attributes.class.value;
        if(classes.includes(key_)){

         sum += this_.actives[key_];

        }

      })
      if(sum > 0) { node_.attributes.fill.value = "#00FF00"; }
      else { node_.attributes.fill.value = "#FF0000"; }
    
    })

  }
  render() {
    return ( <svg id="mockup" width={512} height={512}>
      <rect class={'box active1 active2 active3'} x={64} y={64} width={64} height={64} fill={'#888888'}></rect>
      <rect class={'box active1 active4'} x={160} y={64} width={64} height={64} fill={'#222222'}></rect>
      <rect class={''} x={64} y={140} width={160} height={32} fill={'#0000FF'} onClick={this.clickMe}></rect>
    </svg> )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/d3-react-hooks-forked-2lihv?file=/src/index.js:0-1411

Still looking for filter() approach.